# Biblatex: bibliography section headings without numbers in scrreprt or scrbook

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, koma-script

The following code produces headings on the section level starting with the number of the section before the bibliography:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\begin{document}

\nocite{westfahl:space}\nocite{aksin}\nocite{angenendt}
\nocite{baez/article}\nocite{bertram}\nocite{doody}
\nocite{matuz:doody}\nocite{gillies}\nocite{glashow}
\nocite{herrmann}\nocite{kastenholz}\nocite{reese}
\nocite{sarfraz}\nocite{kant:ku}\nocite{nietzsche:historie}
\nocite{brandt}\nocite{hyman}\nocite{pines}\nocite{moraux}
\nocite{salam}\nocite{cms}\nocite{baez/online}\nocite{ctan}
\nocite{itzhaki}\nocite{markey}\nocite{wassenberg}
\nocite{almendro}\nocite{kowalik}\nocite{laufenberg}
\nocite{sorace}\nocite{jcg}\nocite{chiu}\nocite{padhye}
\nocite{geer}\nocite{loh}

\printbibheading
\printbibliography[notkeyword=secondary,heading=subbibliography,title={Primary Sources}]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary,heading=subbibliography,title={Secondary Sources}]

\end{document}
```

The resulting section header is [image: "0.0 Secondary Sources"]

on the top of page 3 while the header representing the chapter on the top of page 2 is correctly set to "Bibliography". The 0.0 seems wrong. How can I remove it? I tried several combinations with `\defbibheading{subbibliography}` but I did not succeed.
(with biblatex 2.2, biber 1.2)

Comment: Were does your 0.0 apear? I tried your MWE and got no numbers 0.0. If I understand you right, try the class option `bibliography=totocnumbered` to get a numbered chapter `bibliography` in your TOC. Perhaps something missing in your MWE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`biblatex.def` defines

```
\defbibheading{subbibliography}[\refname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \if@twoside\markright{\sectionmarkformat#1}\fi}
```

for `scrbook` and `scrreprt`, which is responsible for the appearance of the number in the header. It disappears if you write, in your preamble,

```
\makeatletter
\defbibheading{subbibliography}[\refname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \if@twoside\markright{#1}\fi}
\makeatother
```

It should be probably filed as bug report to the maintainers of `biblatex`, as `\section*` is used, so no number should be printed in the header and `\sectionmarkformat` just prints the section number along with possibly a dot.

Comment: Thx! Typical case of me not to seeing the wood for the trees... I filed a report [here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/44).

Comment: This has been fixed in biblatex 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: So I was editing my answer and a better one was posted. See what is wrote by egreg.

If I understand well, you want only the name of the section (here Secondary sources), not the chapter and section numbers. You can do it with a tuning of the 
`bibheading` of biblatex with the following lines in your preamble:

```
\defbibheading{subbibliography}{
  \section*{#1}
  \markright{\itshape #1}
}
```

With your MWE it works. I don't know if it answers your question.